# How to close drawer on click in React Native Navigation wix V1

Tags: react-native, drawer, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react native 0.56.0 and React Native Navigation from Wix [V1]. In React native navigation there is an option to enable drawer. Now drawer can be closed if the user chooses some option in drawer menu or click outside the drawer, but I want to close drawer on the X button click. Has anybody found a way to do this?

Comment: which version are you using v1 or v2?

Comment: I am using v1 1.1.476

Answer (score 2):

try this one. its awasome

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

Answer (score 2):

In a custom drawer, there is already a function called closeDrawer inside props.navigation.

Your close button will look like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={props.navigation.closeDrawer}
  style={styles.closeButton}
>
 <Image source={Images.close} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is more code to put things in context:

In App.js

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import DrawerScreen from "./src/screens/DrawerScreen";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function LeftDrawerStack() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerScreen {...props} 
    />} 
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name={"Menu item 1"} component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={"Menu item 2")} component={PaymentScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

In DrawerScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import {TouchableOpacity, View, Image, Text} from 'react-native';
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import styles from './styles/DrawerScreenStyle';


function DrawerScreen(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView style={styles.container} {...props}>
      <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>  
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={props.navigation.closeDrawer}
          style={styles.closeButton}
        >
          <Image source={Images.close} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

export default DrawerScreen;
```

Comment: closeDrawer is a function, so it needs to `props.navigation.closeDrawer();`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
this.props.navigator.toggleDrawer({
    side: 'right',
    animated: true,
    to: 'closed',
});
```

Comment: I will try it and let u know if it works. Thank u for help